# Can I require Logger in all modules automatically?

Tags: elixir

In most of my modules, I

```
require Logger
```

and then do some logging. In modules where I don't, I often make a change that includes adding some logging, and then I have to mark that I'm using the logger.

What's the cost of `require`ing the Logger in every single module? Is there a clean way to just always `require` the Logger without mentioning it in every module?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The main purpose of `require` is to provide an access to *macros* declared in the required module:

> Public functions in modules are globally available, but in order to use macros, you need to opt-in by requiring the module they are defined in.
>   <sub>— from docs for [`Kernel.SpecialForms.require/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#require/2)</sub>

Also, from [Elixir guide](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/meta/macros.html#write-macros-responsibly):

> Macros are lexical: it is **impossible to inject code or macros globally**. In order to use a macro, you need to explicitly require or import the module that defines the macro.

Emphasis is mine. That is done on purpose of your own safety: unlike functions, macros might drastically modify your existing AST. `Logger` is a perfect example of this behaviour: it does not leave any trail in the AST when the level is less than the respective [`compile_time_purge_level`](https://hexdocs.pm/logger/Logger.html#module-application-configuration) specified in config. No single noop. None. Nihil.

That is basically why `Logger` is implemented as a macro.

---

There are two approaches to overcome this behaviour.

**1. Simple. Not recommended.**

Make your own wrapper of `Logger` as *a function*:

```rb
defmodule Log do 
  require Logger
  def log(whatever), do: Logger.log(whatever)
end
```

`Log.log` is now available everywhere (because it’s a *function*.)

*Drawbacks:*

- in production you’ll have `noop` calls to `Log.log` left in the code on `debug` level. That might impact the performance.
- *metadata* (the other reason `Logger` has to be a macro) will be rendered useless — you can't fetch the line number, module, etc of the log-line because they'll always give the site of the macro invocation (credits @NathanielWaisbrot)

**2. Correct. Recommended.**

Make your own `MyApp.Utils` module, which nevertheless exists in every single project slightly more complicated than todo-or-tictactoe-exercise. In this module, save for all your utility functions etc, implement the **macro callback [`__using__`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#use/2)**:

```rb
defmodule MyApp.Utils do
  defmacro __using__(opts \\ []) do
    quote do
      require Logger
      require MyApp.Utils # if this module has macros itself

      def helper, do: Logger.log("Hey, I am always included")
      ...
    end

    ...
  end
end
```

Yes, now in all your modules using `Logger` you have to `use MyApp.Utils` explicitly, but since it nevertheless contains handy helpers that are used application-wide, the `Logger` itself is required for free.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and suggestions. Note that another drawback of solution 1 is that metadata (the other reason Logger has to be a macro) will be rendered useless -- you can't fetch the line number, module, etc of the log-line because they'll always give the site of the macro invocation.

Comment: Indeed; I have somehow missed that while was writing an answer; updated.

Answer (score 0):

Modules do not inherit from a "base" module. There is no inheritance. Think of each module as a self-contained unit of work.

As such, each module should import all the dependencies it needs to do its job. Therefore, requiring Logger in modules that need to do logging is by necessity explicit.